# Nginx as reverse proxy for Apache (RHEL 8), http to https rewrites, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: apache, http, nginx, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have been trying to get a setup with Nginx as reverse proxy for Apache to work with no avail and my brain is starting to melt. I am running a CentOS 8 system with Apache configured to listen only on port 8080. I have one Apache virtual host configured as such:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/example.com

    <Directory /home/user/public_html/example.com>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Nginx is acting as reverse proxy and listening for HTTP and HTTPS connections and the proxying the connection to Apache. domain.com contains a PHP application (Laravel). I have the following server configuration with Nginx:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  root /home/user/public_html/example.com;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
  ssl_session_timeout 60m;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=16000000;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    #proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. I cannot get the application to load, all requests return ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx proxy for apache

```
server {
       listen 443 ssl;
       server_name www.example.com example.com;

       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
       ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
       ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
        location /.git {
            deny all;
            return 404;
        }
}
```

Also check the htaccess for redirection block.